# Sprint planning: dots within the daily capacity of a developer are ignored

Tags: azure-devops

When I define the daily capacity of a developer during a sprint and this value contains a dot (e.g. 2.5 hours), after I save the changes the developer will have a daily capacity of 25 hours.

Daily capacity of the developer before saving the changes:
[image: Capacity of the developer before saving the changes]

Daily capacity of the developer after saving the changes:
[image]

When I use a comma instead of the dot, this problem won't occur.

Is there any way to change this behavior in Azure DevOps, so that the dot can be used instead of the comma?

Comment: Does this have to do with the localization? It looks like the language is set to German. My understanding is that, in Germany, the "." character is used to separate thousands and the "," is used to separate the ones from the tenths place. So in the US, "1,038.45" would be written as "1.038,45" in Germany. Since you don't have enough digits to be thousands, the comma is just being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to override the settings from Azure DevOps is to install the Chrome extension "[Locale Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc)"